# How to use .env to load passport oauth keys in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, laravel-passport

Was trying to use env to load OAuth keys instead of using storage, Larvel keeps complaining of not finding the OAuth keys in storage.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps to solve the problem

1. If you haven't install Passport package in your project, run this command
   `composer require laravel/passport`
2. If you haven't migrated the Passport tables, run this command
   `php artisan migrate`
3. The command below will create encryption keys needed to generate access keys. It will also generate personal access
   `php artisan passport:install`
4. Make sure you remove LoadKeys from AuthServiceProvider to avoid it from loading keys from storage. Remove this line
   `Passport::loadKeysFrom(__DIR__.'/../secrets/oauth');`
5. Publish Passport Configuration, so you will have passport config in the config folder.
   `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-config`
6. The passport config will include private_key, public_key, and personal_access_client configurations
7. If you don't have the keys generated, `php artisan passport:keys` will generate both private and public keys.
8. If you don't have the personal access client generated, `php artisan passport:client` will generate both PASSPORT_PERSONAL_ACCESS_CLIENT_ID and PASSPORT_PERSONAL_ACCESS_CLIENT_SECRET.
9. Your .env file should have these keys

PASSPORT_PERSONAL_ACCESS_CLIENT_ID=""
PASSPORT_PERSONAL_ACCESS_CLIENT_SECRET=""

PASSPORT_PRIVATE_KEY ="-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"

PASSPORT_PUBLIC_KEY="-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"

Your PASSPORT_PRIVATE_KEY and PUBLIC_KEY can be found in the storage folder